# When is it "okay" to briefly exclude self in Python classes for readability?

Tags: python, oop

Started programming a GUI and this also marks my first foray into OOP.

I feel I have a pretty good grasp of why you *should* include `self`. But conversely, I'm still not sure I understand the ramifications of *not* including `self`.

For example,

```
class DataHolder(object):    
    def loadSeries(self, name, filename):
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, ...)
        df = something()
        df = something_else()

        self.meta[name].values = df
```

I've defined a class to help me manage my data. Every time I load in a datafile it needs to be loaded with Pandas and "polished" (e.g. headers, extra columns and stuff removed) until it's ready to be stashed away in some dictionary structure. Here I don't see a reason to keep `df` tied to any object as it's basically a throwaway intermediate result for readability.

Is there anything wrong with this procedure? Could anything go wrong?

Similarly, is there any reason not to make up temporary names in the scope of the method?

```
def refreshPlot(self):
    if self.currentlySelectedName != None:
        self.data.seriesData(self.currentlySelectedName)

        self.canvas.ax.clear()
        self.canvas.ax.plot(self.data.seriesData(self.currentlySelectedName), color = "black")

        if len(self.data.getMeta(self.currentlySelectedName).xdata) == 1:
            self.canvas.ax.axvline(self.data.getMeta(self.currentlySelectedName).xdata[0], color = "red")
        elif len(self.data.getMeta(self.currentlySelectedName).xdata) == 2:
            self.canvas.ax.axvline(self.data.getMeta(self.currentlySelectedName).xdata[0], color = "red")
            self.canvas.ax.axvline(self.data.getMeta(self.currentlySelectedName).xdata[1], color = "red")
    else:
        self.canvas.ax.clear()

    self.canvas.draw()
```

Or I could temporarily assign out readable names:

```
def refreshPlot(self):
    name = self.currentlySelectedName
    xdata = self.data.getMeta(name).xdata

    if name != None:
        data = self.data.seriesData(name)

        self.canvas.ax.clear()
        self.canvas.ax.plot(data, color = "black")

        if len(xdata) == 1:
            self.canvas.ax.axvline(xdata[0], color = "red")
        elif len(xdata) == 2:
            self.canvas.ax.axvline(xdata[0], color = "red")
            self.canvas.ax.axvline(xdata[1], color = "red")
    else:
        self.canvas.ax.clear()

    self.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: You **are** storing your data frame, just not directly on the instance itself but in its `meta` mapping. As for the other, you can use as many local variables as you need to perform your task adequately.

Answer (score 0):

It is a way of programming, an it is not illegal, but one thing that you should keep in mind is that assigning to these variables won't change the class variable.

This is a maintenance risk you take to increase readability, and as a developer that is your own choice. Another downside of this approach can be that, if you do this for a lot of variables, your code has a variable explosion and will still not be readable.

I can understand that you do this, but I would advice to resits the 'this is cleaner' tendency and just accept that this is the way the language is designed. The time-loss and headaches that it can produce do, in my opinion, not justify this design.

Comment: You mean it breaks with the otherwise implicit consistency, e.g. `xdata` could reference two unrelated types of "x-data", depending on the method?

Comment: Yes, since you mimic object retrieval through the non-self variable, but you cannot mimic the assignment. So if you would one day (in the distant future) look at your code and you decide that you want to update ``xdata`` at the end of the method, it will not work. And you or others are left wondering why. It is not that bad at one position, but when you start doing it and it shows up everywhere, the maintainability of the code will be horrible.